# AWS Unity 3D SDK ( Cognito Sync 403 Forbidden Error )

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-cognito

We are developing a mobile game using Unity and we are going to use AWS services to store all the user data and the game content.

We already built all the integration and archived to integrate with the AWS SDK for unity, the DynamoDB and S3 are working as expected but we are have some trouble with CognitoStore.

When we call _ds.Synchronize () or _syncManager.RefreshDatasetMetadataAsync() we get the a 403 Forbidden Error.

> WebException: 403 Forbidden Rethrow as AmazonServiceException: 403
>   Forbidden Rethrow as DataStorageException: Failed to list records in
>   dataset: Account

Simplified policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Full policy at: http://goo.gl/dcUkPC

Code:

```
try {
CognitoSyncClientManager.init();
_syncManager = CognitoSyncClientManager.CognitoSyncManagerInstance;                                     
} catch (Exception ex) {
Debug.LogException (ex);
return;
}

_dsAccount = _syncManager.OpenOrCreateDataset ("Account");
_dsAccount.Put ("test", "1");
_dsAccount.Synchronize ();
```

Not sure if we are missing anything, but i've spent 3 days searching and trying to fix this. I would be thankful if any of you guys can help solve this issue.

Any of you have an idea on how to fix this?

*Note: We are having the same issue with the Unity 3D Sample project.*

**UPDATE 12/02/15**
Updated the SDK to 1.0.1, but i'm getting the error 400 Bad request. Still trying to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the source code is:
`try {
CognitoSyncClientManager.init();
_syncManager = CognitoSyncClientManager.CognitoSyncManagerInstance;          
} catch (Exception ex) {
Debug.LogException (ex);
return;
}

dsAccount = _syncManager.OpenOrCreateDataset ("Account");
_dsAccount.Put ("test", "1");
_dsAccount.Synchronize ();`

Comment: Some additional info that may help us: 1) Are you using authenticated or unauthenticated access? 2) Are you sure your CognitoCredentials are working correctly? 3) You mentioned that S3 and DynamoDB are working, but aren't including in the above policy. Are you sure this the one you are using?

Comment: @BobKinney thanks for the reply. 1) Unauthenticated, but booth works with the other services. 2) I can see all Identities that i used to test and I'm also able to access DynamoDb and S3. 3) I'm using the IAM for full access to S3 and DynamoDB, I just simplified for testing, the full policy is: [Policy](http://goo.gl/dcUkPC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a test on a VM with Windows 7, same project / settings and it worked.

I repeated the test on my mac and it worked.

Not sure yet was was the issue, but opening the same project in Windows and than on Mac again with v1.0.1 aws Unity SDK worked. Maybe was an issue of unity caching or something like that. But it's working.

Thanks!